# why is a component in the error report for generic method call bounded?

Tags: java, generics

In 'Core Java Volume 1', Horstmann recommends this trick from Peter von der Ahé to "purposely introducing an error ... to see which type the compiler infers for a generic method call".

For example, for:

```
//class ArrayAlg
public static <T> T getMiddle(T...a) {
return a[a.length/2];
}
```

Assigning the result as such:

```
JButton aButton = ArrayAlg.getMiddle("Hello", 0, null);
```

will give an error report of:

```
found:
java.lang.Object&java.io.Serializable&java.lang.Comparable<? extends 
   java.lang.Object&java.io.Serializable&java.lang.Comparable<?>>
```

which Horstmann explains: "In plain English, you can assign the result to `Object`, `Serializable`, or `Comparable`.

Question:

I don't understand the last part of the error report `...&java.lang.Comparable<? extends java.lang.Object&java.io.Serializable&java.lang.Comparable<?>>`.

Why is there a bound for `Comparable` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> „*…Why is there a bound for `Comparable` component?…*“

***TL;DR*** — It's complicated. But I think of it very simply: *All three are reported because `String` (aka, *`T`*, aka "Hello")* [***implements all three***](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html).

---

***The long version***

You're seeing the result of a failure of [***one of the compiler's three type inference processes***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-18.html#jls-18-200).

Essentially, type inference tries to figure out: „*Hmm, now what type could `T` be?*“. It determines that *`T`* is an *`Array`* of *something*.

Then it has to figure out, what the *specific* type of the *elements* of that *`Array`* is. To answer that, it examines the generic method's argument(*s*). It makes an [***assertion about compatibilty***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-18.html#jls-18-200-A): „*Since the first argument is of type `String`, and since I already know I'm dealing with an `Array` — and `Array`s always hold the same type — then the other two arguments, logically, must also be of type `String`*“.

Then it does the compiler equivalent of *looking at the Javadoc* to figure out that *`String`* is *compatible* with *`Object & Serializable & Comparable`*.

That's the ***high-level*** „*In plain English*“ overview of why you're seeing *`Comparable`* and the other two in your error message. Read the chapter of the JLS I linked to above if you need the gory details.